# WIX Consume WCF windows Service inside CustomAction

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7

Anyone know how to consume WCF widows service using WIX CustomAction.

Actually my url is this http://[localhost]:8000/WCFWindowsServiceHosting/CustomActions and my wCFWindows services is running provided image [image]

Now using this i need to access my functionality which is written inside WCFWindowsservice.Anyone knows how to achieve this inside WIX CustomAction.

Comment: I tried adding service references into my CustomAction Project and from there trying to consume the service but i am getting error:-Could not find default endpoint element that references contract in the ServiceModel client configuration section. 

This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, 
or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element. Can anyone know's why this is error is comming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of two app.config file inside the CustomAction. As while adding Service reference one more app.config file is creating,so just take the app.config configuration and paste inside CustomAction.config,by this the above error can able solved . Then can able to access the WCF Service inside WIX Custom Action.